# Multitouch in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, multi-touch

Is there a way to simulate in desktop browsers (preferable Chrome) multitouch actions? I tried to emulate touch events with Chrome's emulation, but it seems that I can't make multitouch. The reason that I need this is to have access to element inspector and console in browser after I make scales and rotations.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to download Chrome Canary
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

It allows mobile simulation with pretty good features :
See the tutorial here 
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/mobile-emulation

But there are some restrictions :

> Multi-touch events can be simulated if you have a device with touch input, such as a modern Apple MacBook.

Comment: Must be an intranet, I don't have access to it